# Is Linux process scheduled at timer interrupt only?

Tags: linux, kernel

When Linux process is scheduled, it really happens when timer interrupt is generated and handled, is it right? If wrong, then any further explaination? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Scheduling also occurs whenever a process stops running — most obviously, when a process exits, but also at any point that it makes a system call that causes it to block (i.e, anything that the kernel cannot return a result from immediately).

Answer (score 1):

Partially right. As per current Linux scheduler (CFS), at every scheduler tick, scheduler checks whether is it time to make any preemption. Along with this there are other cases where a task is scheduled - a) when a task is created i.e fork(); b) when a task voluntarily relinquish a CPU i.e by means of calling schedule(); c) When a task is exited.

In case of b & c, there's a possibility that there's no process on current CPU for run. On that particular circumstances - that about to idle CPU tries to load balance i.e tries to transfer load (task) from a busiest CPU to itself and tries to run that particular task. This is a rough summary of how a process on Linux gets scheduled.